# FutureBuilder build error instead of normal section

Tags: flutter, dart

I spend on debugging few days but seems that I have not enough experience or doing something wrong.

I have created small copy-past ready example of error:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TotalDbStat {
  int notificationsTotalCount;

  TotalDbStat({
    this.notificationsTotalCount,    
    });

  factory TotalDbStat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)  {
      return TotalDbStat(
        notificationsTotalCount: 123
      );
  }

}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

    Future<TotalDbStat>  answer = jobStatusTotal();
  
    @override
    build(BuildContext context) {
      return FutureBuilder<TotalDbStat> (
        future: answer,
        builder: (context, snapshot)  {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState)  {
          case ConnectionState.waiting: 
              return Text('Loading....');
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasData) {     
              print(snapshot.data);              
              return Text(snapshot.data.notificationsTotalCount.toString());
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print(snapshot);
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }

            return Text("data");

        }

        }
      );
    }

  }

Future<TotalDbStat> jobStatusTotal() async {
   http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5001/status?total').then((value) {
     if(value.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> valueMap = jsonDecode(value.body)['data'];
        print(valueMap); // this part work I see in console: {notificationsTotalCount: 3948}
        return TotalDbStat.fromJson(valueMap);
     }
     else {
       print("SOME WRONG CODE");
     }

  }).catchError( (e) {
    print(e);
    throw "jobStatusTotal error"; 
    } 
    
    );

    throw "jobStatusTotal error";
 
}
```

Every time I am running it code is going to error and I am getting next result:
[image]

I thought that there is can be issue in model so I tried to hardcode value:

```
notificationsTotalCount: 123
```

But it does not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `jobStatusTotal` does not actually return anything. It just fires of your `then` chains and goes on to throw an exception.

I strongly urge you to use `async`/`await` instead of chaining `.then` because those errors are *way* easier to spot and consequently way harder to make.

This is what your method could look like:

```
Future<TotalDbStat> jobStatusTotal() async {
   const value = await http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5001/status?total');

   if(value.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> valueMap = jsonDecode(value.body)['data'];
      return TotalDbStat.fromJson(valueMap);
   } else {
     print("SOME WRONG CODE");
     return null; // decide what to do here! Maybe throw something?
   }
}
```